# Error report to external BMC inside interrupt handler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

We have one system and an external Baseboard Management Controller (BMC) to monitor this system. When there is a critical error occurred in the system, the error should be logged and sent to the external BMC. The process of sending the error message to the BMC may take a lot of time, as we need to compose the log entry, send the event out via the I2C bus. The error is captured inside the interrupt handler which requires to process the event in a very short time and non-blocking manner. On the other hand, if the error is non-recoverable, the system may reboot immediately.

May you please recommend a good way to handle the error reporting inside the interrupt handler, or is there any standard way for this procedure? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way.

If your BMC communications sleep, you cannot do them from inside the interupt handler and must move them to a workqueue.

If your system reboots immediately after the interrupt handler, you *cannot* communicate with the BMC.

If your interrupt handler actually *knows* that the system will reboot, then you could change the I²C driver to add some method to send data from inside an interrupt handler, by busy-polling instead of sleeping.